# Java - Look and Feel issue

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I'm having a problem with the java look and feel.

I've set it to the Nimbus skin with the following code in my main method:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            boolean found = false;
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
            {               
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found) UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            UIManager.put("AuditoryCues.playList", UIManager.get("AuditoryCues.allAuditoryCues"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

        Manager mngr = new Manager();
        mngr.setSize(1000, 600);
        Utils.centerWindow(mngr);
        mngr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And it gives me this kind of windows:

[image]

As you can see, the JInternalFrames are correctly skinned but the main window is not!

How can I apply the theme to this window too?

Thanks.

---

`Manager` is a simple `JFrame` with the following code:

```
public class Manager extends JFrame
{
    public Manager()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setTitle("My window");
        setIconImage(ImageLoader.getIcon().getImage());

        // My components go here

        pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you call the method which runs the code you've given? Make sure it's the first thing that happens in your program.

Comment: I'm guessing the `Manager` is that main window. That's really weird they're giving different look and feels for the windows. Also, the JInternalFrames don't look like my Nimbus look-and-feels... I'm guessing you're on linux or something though. Without a real SSCCE(.org) I don't think I can help you any further...

Comment: Well, Manager is the main window that is on the joined image. I'm running a custom Windows 7 distrib. Well, what else do you want to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try switching on these two options before frames/dialogs creation:

```
JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated ( true );
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated ( true );
```

This will allow JFrame/JDialog get their decoration from the LaF instead of system.

Comment: I tried but nothing changed at all.
I added the second line just before `Manager mngr = new Manager();`

Comment: I tried this with a few LaFs - it doesn't work only with Nimbus. As i could see from some topics Nimbus seems to use system decoration on Windows-type OS. Don't see any solutions to that though...

Answer (score 3):

- you have read tutorial about [Nimbus Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)
- maybe your issue is about [Changing the Look and Feel After Startup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic)
- edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), demonstrated issue with `main window ???`

Comment: *"I have"*  No you haven't.  2 classes with no imports & a missing 3rd class is ***not*** an SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what to do for you without a good [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), but if you want an example of a method that always works for me you can take a look at [Java-Helper](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/) on github. Specifically, look at the SwingHelper at [this line](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/blob/master/src/com/kentcdodds/javahelper/helpers/SwingHelper.java#L291). I'm adding the code below in order to be in compliance with some of the ground rules of stack overflow ;) Best of luck to you.

```
  /**
   * Sets the look and feel to the given type (like "Nimbus") Learn more here:
   * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
   *
   * @param lookAndFeel to set (like "Nimbus")
   */
  public static void setLookAndFeel(String lookAndFeel) {
    try {
      for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ((info.getName()).equals(lookAndFeel)) {
          javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SwingHelper.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
```